# How to output Tag with Attributes using Notepad++

Tags: xml, xslt, notepad++, xls

I am trying to output an XML via XSL Transformation in Notepad++ using XML Plugin Tool. However the output is not what I expected.

This is my XSL code

```
<ImportValue XSI="foo" DESC="foofoo">
    <xsl:value-of select="foobar"/>
</ImportValue>
```

This is the XML output I get using the tools

```
000010
```

However, I am expecting something more like this

```
<ImportValue XSI="foo" DESC="foofoo">000010</foobar>
```

Does anyone know how to configure this tool to have it formatted so that it does not removed the tag and its attributes? Or is there any other tool that I have no knowledge of?

Thank you.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: It is often a namespace problems if your own code doesn't select or output the result you expect but the built-in templates take over and output the values of text nodes from the input XML. So post a minimal but representative XML input sample and the corresponding XSLT and we can tell more, or first look at the hundreds of examples on how to deal with namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured that I didn't use "<xsl:template match="/">" properly. Solved. Thank you